Proof about properties of a complete binary tree
Let $T$ be a complete binary tree with $N$ nodes and suppose $N$ binary representation is $(b_{n}b_{n-1}...b_{0})$ where $n = \lfloor lg_{2} N \rfloor$. Let $T_{1}$ be the left subtree and $T_{2}$ be the right subtree and $N_{1}$ the number of nodes in $T_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ be the number of nodes in $T_{2}$.
Prove that if $b_{n-1} = 1$ then $N_{1} = 2^{n} - 1$ and $N_{2} = (b_{n-1}...b_{0})$.
What I've tried to do:
I know that $T_{1}$ is a full tree, so it has exactly $2^{n - 1 + 1} - 1$ nodes. And I know that $N = N_{1} + N_{2} + 1$, so it's easy to show that $N_{2} = (b_{n-1}...b_{0})$. But how do I show that if $b_{n-1} = 1$ then $T_{1}$ is a full tree? I know the last level of the tree has at most $2^n$ elements. And if we have at least $2^{n-1}$ elements in the last level, then $T_{1}$ is full, but I can make this link with the binary representation.
